# Autocompletetext view showing blank suggestions

Tags: android

```
ArrayAdapter<String> metroAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,stations);
        source.setThreshold(1);
        destination.setThreshold(1);
        source.setAdapter(metroAdapter);
        destination.setAdapter(metroAdapter);
```

But when I type on on the AutoTCompleteTextView, the suggestions list is shown but is empty. But when I click on any of the blank suggestion, a string is displayed. What seems to be the issue?

**EDIT**
It is working when I change the argument for ArrayAdapter constructor from `getApplicationContext` to `this`. How does that make the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I change the argument for ArrayAdapter constructor from `getApplicationContext` to `this`.
I am not sure how that makes a difference. If someone knows it please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` you use provides theming information to the views that the adapter creates. If you use the application context, it will use the system's styles, not the ones defined for your app. So in general it's not a good idea to inflate layouts using `getApplicationContext()`.

In your case, I guess the options are being shown with the same font color as the background, and therefore theylook blank.

See this article for a good explanation/summary of the different available Contexts an when to use each one: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/